# MVVM detect Validation.HasError in View Model

Tags: wpf

I'm using MVVM and have most of my validation done using IDataErrorInfo and my ViewModel has an IsValid property which checks the validity of each member that needs to be validated. However I have a couple of textboxes bound to ints that can't be null, so I'm using a ValidationRule to alert the user (with a more friendly message than the "value could not be converted" one) if they blank that field out as obviously the property setter never gets called so the IDataErrorInfo code isn't called.

The problem is that I have a Save button (which is a RelayCommand) which I want disabled if there is any validation error. So the CanExecute of that command checks the VM's IsValid property. But obviously if the user blanks my int field the IDataErrorInfo knows nothing about it and currently the button won't disabled. Is there a way that the ViewModel can detect that error?

I thought I'd found a solution here 
http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/forwarding-the-result-of-wpf-validation-in-mvvm/
but having translated it to C# I can't get it working (the Coerce callback is never called). I don't understand dependency properties and objects very well yet (very new to WPF) and this solution looks complicated to me.

The only thing I can think to do is to get rid of the validation rule and make a nullable int wrapper, put TargetNullValue='' in the binding and then I can check them for null in the IDataErrorInfo code. I would prefer not to do this if there's a better way.

Comment: Hi, I've written the blog post you quoted. If you post your C# code, I'll probably be able to tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use string properties instead of int with IDataErrorInfo validation in your viewmodel? in your savecommand you can safely convert your string to your int values, if IDataErrorInfo has no errors of course. Using string properties with IDataErrorInfo is the most easy way.

edit: one more think, there is another problem if you not use string properties. say you have an int Property, and the user set a 10 in your textbox. so in your viewmodel you have the 10. now the user delete the 10 and set a abc in your textbox. your viewmodel still got the 10., because of the bindingconversationexception. thats why i almost use string properties. to be fair you can use behaviors for textbox to set a mask, so the user can not enter invalid data.

Comment: I am subclassing textbox to only accept numbers, but I needed to deal with the blanks so have changed my int property to nullable int (which is a similar principle to string - i.e. let the property setter fire and have IDataErrorInfo deal with it). I've come round to doing it this way as it seems to be the simplest and it seems better doing the validation in just one place.

Comment: its easier or more elegant to use an behavior instead of subclassing :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two strong options right away.  One is to bind to a string property in your ViewModel, which in turn is programmed to only parse and store the underlying 'int' value if the string is determined to be valid.  This ensures that your TextBox will always successfully store its databound value.

The second is to intercept the ValidationExceptions that occur in your View, storing them in your ViewModel via a custom Behavior.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat) will essentially do exactly as you described in your question.

Comment: The second answer looks interesting but I believe I need to download ExpressionBlend which is a no-no. I ended up doing as I originally said i.e. using a nullable int property as my textboxes are all numeric. Gave blindmeis the vote as he/she got there first with the string wrapper which is the same principle but thanks for answering.

Comment: My pleasure.  Just for clarity, you do NOT need Blend for the Behavior functionality; it comes packaged in the (free) Blend SDK, which is a fairly standard SDK for WPF applications.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is `BindingGroups` and have a validation over the whole element, not just single properties. I used this for our modal dialogs to create a project for example, where certain settings must be set before finishing the dialog. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/11/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation.aspx) explained it in good detail. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx) one is also quite detailed.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see anything in those links that involves disabling a command from the ViewModel.

Comment: @Nix Multiple ways, we use a bool property on the viewmodel, which indicates if there are errors, set on the actual validation steps ( which works for BindingGroups and simple IDataErrorInfo validation) and bind the IsEnabled property of the submit button on it. Or you could register to changes of this property and fire the CanExecutedChanged event of the underlying routedcommand. Maybe you could bind to properties inside the bindinggroup directly aswell.